# Application Customizer - problem with deploying?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, deployment, spfx-extensions, applicationcustomizers

I added Application Customizer to my spfx project.
I did following steps to deploy it:

1. gulp clean --ship && gulp build --ship && gulp bundle --ship && gulp package-solution --ship
2. Upload sppkg to AppCatalog
3. Upload build files to CDN
4. Update app version in SiteContents

I have these flags:

```
  "includeClientSideAssets": false,
  "skipFeatureDeployment": false
```

Is there something else that I need to do to deploy an application customizer?